# How to make an application DragDrop aware?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to make an application where I want to drag and drop files from explorer directly to application and a DataGridView updates its entries with the information about the file dropped.

Doing that wasn't an issue but what exactly I wanted is to update the form's UI and display some sort of message like 'Drop files here to update' just when I am over the application holding the file (and not dropped yet).

I found [`Control.GiveFeedback`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.givefeedback) can be used to achieve what I want but somehow even after subscribing to the event, Its not being called.

Here is how I'm handling DragDrop event:

```
 private void dataGridView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
 {
     FileInfo[] DroppedFiles = ((string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)).Select(x => new FileInfo(x)).ToArray();
     foreach (FileInfo File in DroppedFiles)
     {
         TrackInfo Track = new TrackInfo(File.FullName);
         PlaylistSource.Add(Track);
     }
 }
```

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: `DragEnter` or `DragOver` is probably what you want.

Comment: Your Control is the target, not the source.

Comment: @rfmodulator I don't know why it didn't worked before even after so many tries :smh: but now its working as expected. Thank you.!  Will you please post this as an answer so I can mark it solved.

Comment: Perhaps during your trials you set `AllowDrop` to true? You can answer your own question with the code that actually worked for you in the end.

Comment: @rfmodulator I did set the `AllowDrop` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DragOver` and `DragLeave` were the events I had to subscribe in order to let the application aware about a potential `DragDrop` event.

I handled the event like this:

```
private void label1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Link;
        //Updating UI Controls when file dragged over
        label1.BackColor = Color.Green;
        label1.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
}

private void label1_DragLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Updating UI Controls when file no longer being dragged over
    label1.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
    label1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
}
```

Of course, you must not forget to set the control's `AllowDrop` property to actually let the control become "**DragDrop Aware**".